# how to get the values from add remove selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two multiple selection box for caste and sub-caste. Add / Remove button used in both the selection box. I want to filter sub-caste based on caste. how can i get the value of caste selection box. I'm using the code for Add / Remove is

```
$('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#caste option:selected').each( function() {
        $('#caste_new').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
$('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    $('#caste_new option:selected').each( function() {
        $('#caste').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

and also using ajax for fetch the values from database.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not your question, but why do you create new options isteand of just append the existing ones to the new select?

Comment: I want to get the values of caste_new selection box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#caste :input");
```

Should select all inputs that have been appended.
After that you just need to go over the list and fetch value